# Lagrange Polynomials

Tags: c++

I have worked in C language, but now i have been given this work where i will have to use C++.
I have to generate lagrange polynomials. Now, i wont ask for the code or anything but i want to know a few of things:

1. How do i go about this code: I ask the user to enter the data (i.e. the x and y coordinates) around which the polynomial is to be developed and give back a polynomial?
2. Will the same concepts of C let me develop this code in C++ environment, i know there would be a few syntax differences, but would i need to know the classes and objects information for this code or will i be good without them too?
3. If anything else i need to know?

Kindly help!

Comment: C is a subset of C++.  You could code this in straight C and it would work fine on a C++ compiler.  What are you trying to accomplish here?  Is this an interview or homework question?

Comment: read the wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: @Michael Dorgan i knwo i can code it in C, but i have to do it in C++.
Do i need to know a lot about C++ or my knowledge of C will let me code this.

Comment: @Karan: Well the same answer applies. If you write it in C then (barring one or two minor differences) it will also be C++. The real question is whether you have to do it in a C++ **style** because knowing C will not help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pretty much write C and compile it as C++. There might be some exceptions, but hopefully the compiler or a bit or Internet poking should help you there. C++ is a non-strict superset of C.

That said, if you are willing to invest some time in learning the particular facilities of C++, you'll probably find it rewarding. Whether this is worth the time for your particular assignment is a matter of the details of your assignment.

Answer (score -1):

[image]   **this is source code :**

```
#include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        double arrx[2];
    double arrf[2];
    double x, lx;
    int h;
    system("color C");
    //----------------------------------------------
    cout << "________________LAGRANGE  POLYNOMIAL________________" << endl;
    cout << "                                                    " << endl;
    cout << "Enter 3 values For X :" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << "                                                " << endl;
        cout << "X" << i << endl;
        cin >> arrx[i];
    }
    cout << "Enter 3 values For F :" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        cout << "F" << j << endl;
        cin >> arrf[j];
    }
    cout << "How Meany Value ?" << endl;
    cin >> h;
    for (int c = 1; c <= h; c++)
    {
        cout << "______________________________________________________" << endl;
        cout << "Enter f(Value) : " << endl;
        cin >> x;
        cout << "                                                     " << endl;                       //*****Start                                                                                  //****StartTwo            
        lx = ((((x - arrx[1])*(x - arrx[2])) / ((arrx[0] - arrx[1])* (arrx[0] - arrx[2]))) * (arrf[0])) + ((((x - arrx[0])*(x - arrx[2])) / ((arrx[1] - arrx[0])* (arrx[1] - arrx[2]))) * (arrf[1])) + ((((x - arrx[0])*(x - arrx[1])) / ((arrx[2] - arrx[0])* (arrx[2] - arrx[1]))) * (arrf[2]));
        cout << "f(" << x << ")" << "~=" << "L(" << x << ")" << " = " << lx << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 
how lx unreadable ?! 
i write this code it's work !!

Comment: You forgot to write a message.

Comment: Please note that `arrx` and `arrf` are declared as arrays of **two** elements.

Comment: Also avoid `system("pause")` (and friends).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 
no print message is :
cout << "f(" << x << ")" << "~=" << "L(" << x << ")" << " = " << lx << endl;

Comment: i write system("pause") 
because i have bug , so i write this line to stop bug

Comment: At best you masked it.

Comment: Your own screenshot shows that the `system("pause")` fails on your platform. That's what happens when you use platform-specific stuff, on the wrong platform.

Comment: To further clarify Bob's comment - Your code has undefined behavior: You're trying to access a third element (on several `arrx[2]` expressions) on an array that has only two elements (`double arrx[2]`). The same applies for the `arrf` array.